# React Native version mismatch JavaScript version :0.54.3 Native version:0.50.3

Tags: react-native, expo

to solve an other Problem I have to upgrade react native. I used `react-native-git-upgrade 0.54.3` for updating. Is there any idea to upgrade the native verion?

To start my project I used `create-react-native-app`

my package.json contains that:

```
{
  "name": "########",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest-expo": "23.0.0",
    "react-native-scripts": "1.8.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^6.3.1",
    "exp": "^47.4.4",
    "expo": "^23.0.4",
    "react": "16.3.0-alpha.1",
    "react-native": "0.54.3",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.13",
    "react-navigation": "^1.5.8"
  }
}
```

The image is describing my problem very exactly.

[image: The image is describing my problem very exactly]

If try to execute watchman cmd says that watchman is unknown

## update:

I updated my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ProdPrototype",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest-expo": "^25.1.0",
    "react-native-scripts": "^1.11.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.2.0"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^6.3.1",
    "connect": "^3.6.6",
    "exp": "^50.0.5",
    "expo": "^25.0.0",
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-24.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.13",
    "react-navigation": "^1.5.8"
  }
}
```

deleted node_modules and ran `npm install` didn't worked, same error.

Comment: Is it due to an old `packager` running already?

Comment: No there is no other packager running.

Answer (score 0):

```
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-24.0.0.tar.gz",
```

put this line in your dependencies in package.json file